# Model performance not improving during federated learning training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-federated

I have followed [this emnist tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) to create an image classification experiment (7 classes) with the aim of training a classifier on 3 silos of data with the TFF framework.

Before training begins, I convert the model to a tf keras model using `tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(model,state.model)` to evaluate on my validation set. Regardless of the label, the model only predicts one class. This is to be expected as no training of the model has occurred yet. However, I repeat this step after each federated averaging round and the problem persists. All validation images are predicted to one class. I also save the tf keras model weights after each round and make predictions on the test set - no changes.

Some of the steps I have taken to check the source of the issue:

1. Checked if the tf keras model weights are updating when the FL model is converted after each round - they are updating.
2. Ensured that the buffer size is greater than the training dataset size for each client.
3. Compared the predictions to the class distribution in the training datasets. There is a class imbalance but the one class that the model predicts is not necessarily the majority class. Also, it is not always the same class. For the most part, it predicts only class 0.
4. Increased the number of rounds to 5 and epochs per round to 10. This is computationally very intensive as it is quite a large model being trained with approx 1500 images per client.
5. Investigated the TensorBoard logs from each training attempt. The training loss is decreasing as the round progresses.
6. Tried a much simpler model - basic CNN with 2 conv layers. This allowed me to greatly increase the number of epochs and rounds. When evaluating this model on the test set, it predicted 4 different classes but the performance remains very bad. This would indicate that I just would need to increase the number of rounds and epochs for my original model to increase the variation in predictions. This is difficult due the large training time that would be a result.

Model details:

The model uses the XceptionNet as the base model with the weights unfrozen. This performs well on the classification task when all the training images are pooled into a global dataset. Our aim is to hopefully achieve a comparable performance with FL.

```
base_model = Xception(include_top=False,
                      weights=weights,
                      pooling='max',
                      input_shape=input_shape)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()( x )
predictions = Dense( num_classes, activation='softmax' )( x )
model = Model( base_model.input, outputs=predictions )
```

Here is my training code:

```
def fit(self):
    """Train FL model"""
    # self.load_data()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(
        self.logs_dir
    )
    federated_averaging = self._construct_iterative_process()
    state = federated_averaging.initialize()
    tfkeras_model = self._convert_to_tfkeras_model( state )
    print( np.argmax( tfkeras_model.predict( self.val_data ), axis=-1 ) )
    val_loss, val_acc = tfkeras_model.evaluate( self.val_data, steps=100 )

    with summary_writer.as_default():
        for round_num in tqdm( range( 1, self.num_rounds ), ascii=True, desc="FedAvg Rounds" ):

            print( "Beginning fed avg round..." )
            # Round of federated averaging
            state, metrics = federated_averaging.next(
                state,
                self.training_data
            )
            print( "Fed avg round complete" )
            # Saving logs
            for name, value in metrics._asdict().items():
                tf.summary.scalar(
                    name,
                    value,
                    step=round_num
                )
            print( "round {:2d}, metrics={}".format( round_num, metrics ) )
            tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(
                tfkeras_model,
                state.model
            )
            # tfkeras_model = self._convert_to_tfkeras_model(
            #     state
            # )
            val_metrics = {}
            val_metrics["val_loss"], val_metrics["val_acc"] = tfkeras_model.evaluate(
                self.val_data,
                steps=100
            )
            for name, metric in val_metrics.items():
                tf.summary.scalar(
                    name=name,
                    data=metric,
                    step=round_num
                )
            self._checkpoint_tfkeras_model(
                tfkeras_model,
                round_num,
                self.checkpoint_dir
            )
def _checkpoint_tfkeras_model(self,
                              model,
                              round_number,
                              checkpoint_dir):
    # Obtaining model dir path
    model_dir = os.path.join(
        checkpoint_dir,
        f'round_{round_number}',
    )
    # Creating directory
    pathlib.Path(
        model_dir
    ).mkdir(
        parents=True
    )
    model_path = os.path.join(
        model_dir,
        f'model_file_round{round_number}.h5'
    )
    # Saving model
    model.save(
        model_path
    )

def _convert_to_tfkeras_model(self, state):
    """Converts global TFF modle of TF keras model

    Takes the weights of the global model
    and pushes them back into a standard
    Keras model

    Args:
        state: The state of the FL server
            containing the model and
            optimization state

    Returns:
        (model); TF Keras model

    """
    model = self._load_tf_keras_model()
    model.compile(
        loss=self.loss,
        metrics=self.metrics
    )
    tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(
        model,
        state.model
    )
    return model

def _load_tf_keras_model(self):
    """Loads tf keras models

    Raises:
        KeyError: A model name was not defined
            correctly

    Returns:
        (model): TF keras model object

    """
    model = create_models(
        model_type=self.model_type,
        input_shape=[self.img_h, self.img_w, 3],
        freeze_base_weights=self.freeze_weights,
        num_classes=self.num_classes,
        compile_model=False
    )

    return model

def _define_model(self):
    """Model creation function"""
    model = self._load_tf_keras_model()

    tff_model = tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        model,
        dummy_batch=self.sample_batch,
        loss=self.loss,
        # Using self.metrics throws an error
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()] )

    return tff_model

def _construct_iterative_process(self):
    """Constructing federated averaging process"""
    iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
        self._define_model,
        client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( learning_rate=0.02 ),
        server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( learning_rate=1.0 ) )
    return iterative_process
```

Answer (score 1):

> 4. Increased the number of rounds to 5 ...

Running only a few *rounds* of federated learning sounds insufficient. One of the earliest Federated Averaging papers ([McMahan 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629)) required running for hundreds of rounds when the MNIST data had non-iid splits. More recently ([Reddi 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.00295)) required thousands of *rounds* for CIFAR-100. One thing to note is that each "round" is one "step" of the global model. That step may be larger with more client epochs, but these are averaged and diverging clients may reduce the magnitude of the global step.

> I also save the tf keras model weights after each round and make predictions on the test set - no changes.

This can be concerning. It will be easier to debug if you could share the code used in the FL training loop.

Comment: That's really helpful - thanks. I will try increasing the number of rounds. 

I have included my training code as an edit to the my original post above. Please let me know if I can include any further information to help with the debugging.

Comment: Would you suggest to change the optimizer? If one was to try FedAdam, would that involve just changing the server_optimizer_fn in the construction of the iterative process or would more significant changes be required?

Comment: Yes, essentially FedAdam is changing the server optimizer to Adam. Note that in that the Reddi paper it was important to use a much higher `epsilon` than the default 1e-8 (I believe the paper use 0.1 or 0.001). A few other things that can be interesting to investigate: number of client epochs. More early on can help convergence, but can harm final accuracy so this can be tricky.