# Epochs vs Rounds in federated learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I am applying federated averaging on my federated learning model. After running the model for thousands rounds the model still did not converged.
How can I increase the number of epochs in training, and how it differs from the number of rounds?
And how can I reach to convergence, since I tried to increase the number of rounds but it take long time to train (I am using Google Colab, and the execution time can not be more than 24 hours I also tried subscribed to Google Colab Pro to use the GPU but it did not work well)

The code and the training results are provided below

```
train_data = [train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(c).repeat(2).map(reshape_data)
.batch(batch_size=50,num_parallel_calls=50)
 for c in train_client_ids]

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.9))

NUM_ROUNDS = 50000
state = iterative_process.initialize()

logdir = "/tmp/logs/scalars/training/"
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

with summary_writer.as_default():
  for round_num in range(0, NUM_ROUNDS):
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, train_data)
    if (round_num% 1000) == 0:
      print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))
      for name, value in metrics['train'].items():
        tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=round_num)
```

And the output in shown in
[image: this image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification#preprocessing_the_input_data) for how to increase epochs (basically increase the number in `.repeat()`). The number of epochs is the number of iterations a client train on each batch. The number of rounds is the total number of federated computation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My first question was (how can I reach to convergence?) or if there is any approach that fasten the model convergence. based on this [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682329/18726545) can we explain the process of one single round as (Broadcasting the global model to the clients and then aggregate the updated model) by the server?

Comment: Yes, that's what one single round does. Tuning the number of epochs, increasing number of rounds, and changing learning rate might help with the convergence.